# How to save a float to an integer column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This should just work with ease:

```
b = Balance.first
b.total = 2.20
b.save #=> 2.2
b #=> 2
```

Total's table column is an integer `:integer`. Do I need to set the table as float as the decimal is not registered?

Here is the Rails 4 part; when the form is submitted, I have in the `Balance` model:

```
...

before_save :balance_to_float

def balance_to_float
  self.total = self.total.to_f
end

...
```

Sill not getting the float. Have I missed something with Ruby 2.3?

Comment: Set `total` column as a float and it should be fine

Comment: Tried that but still not showing as float. Its not in the db as float. Im using postgres

Comment: You will need to migrate old data since they have been cast as integers before you set the column as float

Comment: Ok ill try that in a bit. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"the decimal is not registered"*?

Comment: Decimal as in the .02. Decimal to me means the "."

Comment: I see, that's the *fractional part*. BTW, you should not use float for currency values. Either use decimal (`BigDecimal` in Ruby and `DECIMAL` in SQL) or use an integer and store the cents (i.e. store `2.2` as `220`). The latter is used by the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem.

Comment: @Stefan I would up vote your last comment 5 more times if I could. Float math gets ugly fast and can create debugging nightmares if you do not realize the implications.

Comment: I hate using too many gems. There must be a better way

Comment: @Sylar you don't have to use a gem. money-rails provides mapping between cent values stored as integers and instances of `Money`. You can easily write your own wrappers or just use decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a `float` in an `integer` column. Because an integer (from the Latin integer meaning "whole") is a number that can be written without a fractional component.

You must change your column's type to `float` or `decimal` (depending on your needs).

Comment: Yes I had to revisit my ruby knowledge and saw that.